# iphone ios application home button press/applicationDidEnterBackground crash

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit

hallo, i am newbie in developing iphne/ios application and i have
encountered some problem

generrraly my app (which is iphone camera image processing app) has no
visible errors at today stage except the one

when i press the home button to send my app off screen (putting to the
background), and then press the app icon to 'wake it up' again 
it crashes

what would it be...? what the reason of it would be?
what is done to my app (seen from the view of programmer
- i mean internal game state) by this home buton operation?
- what i should take care of before "applicationDidEnterBackground"
eventually?

thanx for answer

Comment: Do you have a crash log, with out it is really only guess work.

Comment: And you need to symbolicate your crash log before posting it.

Comment: also post "applicationDidEnterBackground" code

Comment: should i assure (by some flag setted in applicationDidEnterBackground) and stop my code manually or can do nothing and it will freeze automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Is this happening when you are running it from Xcode? Xcode does not like it if you hit the home button and start it again from within the device/simulator. Is it crashing if you launch it from the device (or simulator) without Xcode running? If not, then there probably isn't a problem.

Comment: both, when 'woke up' it is like it freeze for 1 second, then closes and thats all; under xcode it stops in the debbugger buti do not have normal callstack only "0 objc_msgSend  4 _phtread_wqthread" and some assembly in main window.  I have no code at all applicaionDidEnterBackground() - should i put some flag isStopped  there and assure that my application after that will not do anything or it will freeze automatically - sorry for basic question